# Firebase OIDC discovery

Tags: javascript, firebase, openid-connect

I'm trying to to connect to a OIDC discovery server that requires custom header such as Client id when trying to connect to the discovery server.

Example:
https://oidc-baseurl/oauth2/.well-known/openid-configuration (<- Base URL)
I added all information with Firebase -> Sign-in providers. It will only return the base issuer, because this does not pass any client-id in the header.

I tested on postman calling the base URL and added the heaeder with the client-id, and it will return the right issuer to me.

How do I set the customized header when trying to use Firebase OIDC ? I do not see any related implementation in the documentation.

Only thing close to this is customParamter did not work well.

Thanks!